# Keep files (modules) as "big" as possible

Tags: python

In my company, we have this best practice:

> For simplicity reasons, keep files as big as possible. 
>   Avoid splitting them in smaller files.

This comes from one of the most experimented guy in Python we had (but no longer in the company).

This goes against my intuition. In most other languages, I tend to keep modules (or their equivalent) as small as possible to limit coupling.

I did not find much documentation about this:

- is this shared by the Python community?
- what is the reason for that? (if it is purely opinionated, the question stops here)